# Pros and Cons of encrypting Web.config

Tags: .net, encryption, web-config, rsa

I am currently using **RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider** for encrypting web.config. Could there be any pros or cons of encrypting web.config file for a published website?

Currently my application has 50 users but it is gonna increase in future.

Answer (score 1):

Not only that it is recommended it is practically **mandatory** in a production environment.

The app/web.config is where you store your database credentials, message queue credentials, and various other sensitive information.
Even if you are using integrated security (which is good) you still should encrypt your web.config , or at least the sections with sensitive information.

**Con**: unreadable or at least with no decryption key it required some work to decrypt.

**Con**: sometimes hard to change on the fly, since it is not readable.

But these cons are less of an issue in a production environment, need to update your config file? just overwrite it.